# Check variable true with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
$(val1).mouseleave(function () {
    flag = false;
    $(val3 + "," + val4).mouseenter(function () {

        flag = true;
        //alert(flag);

    });
    if (flag == true) {
        //alert("if"+flag);
        $(".big" + i + j + "boxer").show();
        $(".big" + i + "box").show();
        $(".big" + i + "box").append('<div class="opacity" style="background-color:rgba(00,00,00,0.77);position:absolute;top:0;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;"></div>')
        $(".small" + i + "box").append('<div class="opacity" style="background-color:rgba(00,00,00,0.77);position:absolute;top:0;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;"></div>')

    } else {
        //alert("else"+flag);
        $('.opacity').remove();
        $(val2).hide();
        $(val3).show();

    }
});
```

It's not meeting `flag = true` condition. If I `alert` within `$(val1).mouseleave(function(){});`,  it shows that  `flag = true`; but when I alert it outside of `$(val1).mouseleave(function(){});`,  it shows `flag = false`.

Well, let me explain: I have 4 blocks `val1,val2,val3` and `val4`. When the users leave `val1` and enter the `val3` or `val4` block, I want to `set/add opacity class` ... if they `do not enter` into `val3/val4` but *go* into `val2 or another block` block then I want to remove opacity class.

Comment: could you post the html?

Comment: hi @wilsonrufus i tried flag=== true... but did not work...

Comment: Are any of the blocks nested inside each other? If not, are they positioned next to each other with no space in between, or _with_ space in between, or...? Perhaps you could show the html, and possibly include a demo at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: k try this window.flag = true & window.flag = false not sure if this will work

Comment: no they are separted from each other.. atleast there is 1px space separting them...

Comment: @wilsonrufus i tried ur code.. its giving false again...

Comment: try writting the ifelse inside mouseenter()

Comment: but i iam calling mouseeneter only `if the flag is true` ,,, else i do not want to call .

Comment: if try another variable maybe that u set to true in mouseEnter

Answer (score 8):

At the point where you do the if test:

```
if(flag==true)
```

...`flag` will *always* be false, because you set it to `false` just before that. The only place it gets set to `true` is inside the `mouseenter` handler that you bind there but that handler function doesn't get called at that point.

Let me add some comments to the beginning of your code to try to make that clearer:

```
$(val1).mouseleave(function () {
    flag = false;                                  // set flag to false
    $(val3 + "," + val4).mouseenter(function () {  // bind a mouseenter
        flag = true;                               // that won't be called immediately
        //alert(flag);                             // so won't change flag yet
    });
    if (flag == true) {                            // flag is still false
```

It doesn't make sense to bind a `mouseenter` handler from inside the `mouseleave` handler, because that means every time the mouseleave occurs you bind an additional `mouseenter` handler to the same elements.

I can't really suggest a specific solution because you haven't explained what effect you are trying to achieve. (But I'd probably start by moving that `mouseenter` code somewhere else.)

Comment: thanks for answering ...any alternative ways to fix this?how can we use if condition within jquery in that case?

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to achieve? Please describe in terms of "When the user moves the mouse [somewhere], do [something]."

Comment: hi @nnnnnn i have edited my question please check it....i got your point but iam actually looking for an alternative solution to fix this...

Comment: Check @mibbler's answer, it's pretty much what I would have suggested after seeing your clarification.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(val1).mouseleave(function () {
    flag = false;
    $(val3 + "," + val4).mouseenter(function () {

        flag = true;
        //alert(flag);
        if (flag == true) {
        //alert("if"+flag);
        $(".big" + i + j + "boxer").show();
        $(".big" + i + "box").show();
        $(".big" + i + "box").append('<div class="opacity" style="background-color:rgba(00,00,00,0.77);position:absolute;top:0;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;"></div>')
        $(".small" + i + "box").append('<div class="opacity" style="background-color:rgba(00,00,00,0.77);position:absolute;top:0;right:0;left:0;bottom:0;"></div>')

    } else {
        //alert("else"+flag);
        $('.opacity').remove();
        $(val2).hide();
        $(val3).show();

    }

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks alot for for your attempt @wilsonrufus but i have already tried this... in this case it does not take `flag=false` ,it always takes `flag=true`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have clarified your objective, I think something like this would work:

```
var haveLeft = null;    

$(val1).mouseleave(function () {
    haveLeft = "val1";
});

$(val2).mouseenter(function () {
    if(haveLeft === "val1") {
        // remove opacity class
    }        
}).mouseleave(function(){
    haveLeft = "val2";
});

$(val3 + "," + val4).mouseenter(function () {
    if(haveLeft === "val1") {
        // add opacity class
    }
}).mouseleave(function(){
    haveLeft = "val3/4";
});
```

Comment: +1. This is very similar to what I would've suggested had the requirement been specified up front - close enough that there's no point in my updating my own answer.